# in drop down list how to select text by index?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

Please guide me in asp.net drop down list how to find text of an item if its index is known. Please also guide me is there any issue in that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do using index with `Items` Collection to get the text.

```
string text = Dropdownlist1.Items[index].Text;
```

*There is no issue to access the text of dropdown.*